# using a good streaming mp4, Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have many greenway trail mp4 movies from Sony helmet cam. I have a sample 7 minute raw movie from the camera uploaded to my hosting domain for the movies.

Chrome and Firefox stream it correctly. When I edit it and publish it to same place, the startup streaming pauses off and on, stalls, pauses, for a while... then finally plays okay.  That is why I am am here.

I am trouble-shooting that issue, because trying to fix them has the same issue I have on this raw, working correctly movie file.

I get the same error.

I am new with this tool and need help identifying the cause of the error.
This is the raw file:

http://rnc3.net/clips/media/puzzle107/MAH00107.MP4

```
ffmpeg MAH00107.MP4 -movflags faststart outputfile.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfree type --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-

libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Output #0, mp4, to 'MAH00107.MP4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Answer (score 12):

You forgot the `-i` to indicate which file is an input. Change your command to:

```
ffmpeg -i MAH00107.MP4 -movflags faststart outputfile.mp4
```